# Wait time for a bus

Tags: probability, statistics

For a morning commute let the time spent waiting for a bus =Y. Assume the minimum wait time is 2 min and that is is impossible for the wait time to exceed 14 min.

A)Propose a probability model for the distribution of Y.

B) if the mean is 8 and SD is 2 and it is more likely that the wait time will occur closer to the mean what is an alternative probability model assuming a symmetric distribution

Comment: Keep in mind that on average you'll wait longer than average.

Comment: What distributions do you know that are constrained to be in an interval? For part (A), you must have a bounded random variable.

Comment: You should find a couple of distributions that maximizes the entropy subject to those constraints. With this approach, the answer is in fact a Uniform distribution for case (a).

Comment: What if for part A) the probability to the wait time is proportional to the wait tiem

Comment: Then you need a linearly increasing density function on the interval $[2,14].$

Comment: Usually the amount of time it takes to wait for a bus is equal to the length of a famous ZZtop song

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For A, since we know nothing about the difference in probability, it's a uniform distribution $U(2,14)$.

For B, a more fitting model is a normal distribution (which has the desired qualities) with expected value $8$ and variance $2^2 = 4$.

Comment: The problem with the normal is that it doesn't respect the minimum and maximum constraints.

Comment: How about a triangular distribution?

Answer (score 0):

Okay here is my answer.  Say that the bus comes every $12$ minutes.  Where you arrive on a twelve minute interval can be modeled by a uniform distribution.  However the bus at the start of the twelve minute interval (bus 1) can be early/late and the bus at the end of the interval (bus 2) also early or late.  Model these with a normal distributions (iid) centered at $0$ with standard deviation $\sigma$.  (These are only approximately normal.)  Now if bus 1 is late and you're early enough on the interval, you get bus 1.  If not, and if you beat bus 2, you will get on bus 2.  However, if you arrive at the end of the interval and bus 2 is early, then you will have to wait through another $12$-ish minutes to get on bus 3.  You find that you will wait on average longer than $6$ minutes.  This is the bus paradox.

(I used to ride the bus a lot.  It gives you a lot of time to think.)